# Run-time error '1004' when applying formula to Range.FormulaR1C1 in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to apply a big nested formula to a range using the code below.  Basically, if the value in cell A of the active row exists in the column A of another workbook and if the cell in column E of the active row is not empty, I want the active cell to display the cells to display the value of the equivalent cell in a separate workbook.

This needs to be applied to several worksheets so I'm using the variables `lrow` (which is an `int` with the last row of the active worksheet in workbook#1) and `tlrow` (which is an `int` equal to the last row of the active worksheet in workbook#2). When I step through the sub, these variables both return the numbers I would expect them to.

Likewise, this is inside of a for loop so I also use `Worksheets(i).Name` where `I` is an `int`.

When I run the code, I get the run-time error "'1004': Application-defined or object-defined error".

I'm assuming it's a syntax issue.

**Code:**

```
Range("B15:B" & lrow).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(OR(RC1="""",RC5=""""),"""",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,'[temp.xlsx]" & _
    Worksheets(i).Name & _
    "'!A15:D" & tlrow & ",3,FALSE)),""0"",VLOOKUP(RC1,'[temp.xlsx]" & _
    Worksheets(i).Name & "'!A15:D" & tlrow & ",3,FALSE))))"
```

Comment: Is the error generated on the line you've given? Have you tried using a simple formula first (such as `"=2+2"`, then building it up?

Comment: I think you've kinda mixed things up between `R1C1` and `A1` notation when you construct your formula. If you use `R1C1` notation, it should be consistent throughout the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
Range("B15:B" & lrow).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(OR(RC1="""",RC5=""""),"""",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1," & _
    Worksheets(i).Range("A1:D" & lrow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=True) & _
    ",3,FALSE)),""0"",VLOOKUP(RC1," & _
    Worksheets(i)..Range("A1:D" & tlrow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=True) & _
    ",3,FALSE)))"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This code didn't throw an error but what happened was the vlookup range was applied to "A1:D" & tlrow of the active worksheet instead of being applied to the equivalent range in the workbook "temp.xlsx".  Do you know how I would get around this?  Thanks!

Comment: @Inderbitzen Ah I assumed you have correctly referenced the sheet you are working on, in this case `Worksheets(i)`. What you did in your posted answer is the right thing to do. Good job for sorting it out.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Excel are you running? In more recent versions you can use the Iferror function in this formula to really chop down the size.

It would be something like this:

```
Range("B15:B" & lrow).FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF(OR(RC1="""",RC5=""""),"""",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1," & " & Worksheets(i).Range("A1:D" & _
tlrow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=True) & ",3,0),""0"")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.  I was able to resolve the problem by defining my vlookup range in a Range variable and then inputting the variable name in L42's equation in place of

```
 worksheets(i).Range("A1:D" & lrow)
```

Really apprecaite the responses! Thanks again.